# Is there a java collection that allows for a one-key-to-multiple-values relationship?

Tags: java

I have a need for a collection type that allows for a multiple values to be associated with multiple keys.  Ideally, I would use it like Map, but map is intended for a given key to yield a single value.

Below is an example of how I would like to use this:

```
@Test
public void multipleItems() {
    Index<String, String> index = new Index<String, String>();
    index.add("key1", "value1");
    index.add("key2", "value2");
    index.add("key1", "value3");
    index.add("key2", "value4");
    index.add("key1", "value5");

    List<String> values = index.get("key2");

    assertEquals(2, values.size());
    assertEquals("value2", values.get(0));
    assertEquals("value4", values.get(1));
}
```

I am not aware of any implementation in the JVM.  I could implement this myself, but I am hoping to find an existing implementation.

Recommendations?

**SOLUTION**

Based on the recommendations below, I ended up using the guava (and wrapping it as I didn't want to expose this to the rest of my app in case I found a better solution.

I used [these settings](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava-collections/r03) for including through my gradle scripts:  `'com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03'`

My "wrapper" class looks like this:

```
public class Indexes<K, V> {

    private HashMultimap<K, V> keyToValuesMap = HashMultimap.create();

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        this.keyToValuesMap.put(key, value);
    }

    public Set<V> get(K key) {
        return this.keyToValuesMap.get(key);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with a `Map` that maps your keys to some other type of container that will hold the values that go with that key?  (E.g., `Map<String, List<String>>`)

Comment: @Blrfl: nope, nothing wrong with rolling-my-own, just trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel.  Less likely to create a bug the less source code that I have.  Also, was hoping to find a thread-safe approach (guava partially gets me there)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), the java library from Google, has several types of [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)s, including [`ListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) and [`SetMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html), with a variety of implementations.  There's also a [wiki article](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap).

Answer (score 3):

To go along with the other answers, you can roll your own via `Map<String, List<String>>` or `Map<String, Set<String>>` if you cannot use a 3rd party library as well.

Comment: I did indeed roll my own for a first pass, and quite easy.  I ended up using the guava implementation as a final version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multimap in java.
See this for more information.

http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html